# What do these anagrams have in common? #2

Tags: anagram

> - Agar man
> - Red Lid
> - Ripcords Crow Cysts
> - I perch
> - Libya Oils Tv

What do these anagrams have in common?
Hopefully this one is a little harder!

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Possibly too easy / not challenging / Just don't like. I didn't DV though. In general, anagram-riddles are a bit boring/easy though, unless some special "spin" is attached. There are plenty of online-tools to help you solve them, and at one point they become no longer solvable on their own. For me, this puzzle is "okay" but not great.

Comment: I downvoted because it's unchallenging and uninteresting.

Comment: @BmyGuest Thanks for the input! I'll try and make my puzzles better in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're all

> Tags on Puzzling.SE!

Agar man

> anagram

Red Lid

> riddle

Ripcords Crow Cysts

> Cryptic crossword

I perch

> cipher

Libya Oils Tv

> solvability

Comment: I think I'll give it to this one, since it's the first complete answer.

Comment: Yes, it was a race.

Comment: @BmyGuest When I started writing my answer, I didn't even that see anyone else had posted yet! The last one was definitely the hardest since it's not commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

They are all

> Puzzling StackExchange tags

Agar man

> anagram

Red Lid

> Riddle

Ripcords Crow Cysts

> Cryptic crossword

I perch

> Cipher

Libya Oils Tv

> Solvability

Comment: Beat me to it. But I'm missing the last one right now...

Comment: Can show the answers to the tags?

Answer (score 0):

Easy!

> All of them are tags from this site.
>  Anagram, Riddle, Cryptic Crosswords, Cipher, ...